# Bootstrap 3 popovers not moving along with elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, user-experience

I am new to front end development and I am really seeking for the solution.

Basically I have this input fields in the page and validated each of them using ajax. Now, if something is wrong with the texts inputted to the element, I returned a validation error from the backend and let the frontend show a popover. I also have a form which prepends new fields to the top of my table.

So the scenario is a popover is already shown in the top row of the table. Whenever a new row is added (dynamically) to the table, the popover should go with the previous row attached to it ( which is now the second row of the table ).

Expected result:
Popover should go along with the second row.

Actual Result:
the popover stay at the first row telling me a user that the first row has validation errors.

EDIT ( the code )

```
// JS Triggered by ajax success where validation error is returned
var $el = $("#email");
$el.popover({
  content: "Invalid value!",
  placement: 'top',
  container: 'body'
});

// html 
<tr>
  <td> <input id="email"  type="text" value="something*#@email.com"/> </td>
</tr>
```

PS: sorry for my bad english.

Thanks!

Comment: Care to show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve [this](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/dFdLG/), just add this to your input

```
rel="popover"
```

Comment: Hi actually, I tried updating the fiddle you gave but to my suprise, it worked only for that set of html. I tried it to our project code and it doesn't work. Well, the only difference is that our inputs are inside a table.

Comment: I suggest you take my basic jsfiddle and add your html line by line and testing it in the same time until you will see it is not working anymore. Than you will know where does the problem comes from.  Probably some errors in your code. Anyways, there is no other solution for your problem, this is the solution and i showed you it work's, depend's on you from now on to check your code errors.

Comment: Yes, your solution worked. I was trying to upvote your answer but I can't right now due to some lacking repu. But anyways, thanks!

Comment: No problem. There are 2 things that you can do when an answere is good. Either up' vote it, either mark it as good. There is a check mark exactly under the the number of votes.